# How to make a Team Page like publicis.com/people

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to create a team page similar to my www.publicis.in/people/ this site using Jquery but not able crack it.

I am not able to scale the current div and move the left div to -left and right divs to the right with effects.

Kindly Help!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide some code, what have you tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey , 
Here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/monit/a34ssyuL/2/